# How to call async method in sync method in .net core

Tags: asynchronous, .net-core, async-await

I found some ways to call an async method on a sync method, but I don't know what is the **best way** in .net core and **why**?

```
DebugLog.Log(ex.ToString()).GetAwaiter();
System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Run(async () => await DebugLog.Log(ex.ToString()));
DebugLog.Log(ex.ToString()).RunSynchronously();
DebugLog.Log(ex.ToString()).ConfigureAwait(default);
```

Comment: see this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9343594/how-to-call-asynchronous-method-from-synchronous-method-in-c

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to call asynchronous method from synchronous method in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9343594/how-to-call-asynchronous-method-from-synchronous-method-in-c)

Answer (score 0):

> I don't know what is the best way in .net core and why?

There is no best way. If there was, then everyone would just use that.

There are a [variety of approaches, each with their own drawbacks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2015/july/async-programming-brownfield-async-development). The two most common are:

1. `GetAwaiter().GetResult()` (i.e., direct blocking) - [can deadlock](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html).
2. `Task.Run(...).GetAwaiter().GetResult()` (i.e., block a thread pool thread) - doesn't work if the `...` requires the current context.

`RunSynchronously` [should never be used](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2015/02/a-tour-of-task-part-8-starting.html).